# ignore retina on universal app and force retina ipad to use ipad2 version of app

Tags: ipad

how can you force an app to run the ipad2 version of a universal app and ignore the retina ipad on a retina ipad? Can you remove the retina assets of a game you didn't develop so that you can use the ipad2 version instead of the retina version? is there anything in the info.plist, resource.plist, etc that one could change so that the Ipad2 version of an app runs instead of the Retina version?

Answer (score 0):

Removing all Retina assets from the Xcode project should be sufficient in most cases.

Comment: how do you create a project in xcode if the app isnt yours? maybe im not allowed to ask that question.